# Error_message: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having a problem with my code: when I make a search in the i-th column of the matrix it gives me the following error:

```
if grades[:,i]!=-3:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I have tried to read the older posts on this issue, but can't really relate to my problem

I am trying to program a grading function according to danish grading-scale

```
def computeFinalGrades(grades):
    #looping over the leth of grades
    for i in range(len(loopingrange)):
        #checking if any grade in the i-th coloumn is -3  
        if grades[:,i]==-3:
        #if a grade is equal to -3 then the output variabel gradesFinal is -3  
            gradesFinal = -3
        else:
        #looping over all grade coloumns that do not contain one or more grades of -3
            for i in range(len(loopingrange)):
              #Checking to see if any coloumn only contains 1 grade  
                if (len(grades[:,i]) == 1):
              # if a coloumn only contains 1 grade - that is also the final grade      
                    gradesFinal = grades[:,i]
               #Checking to see if coloumn contains more than 1 grade and those grades are not -3     
                elif (len(grades[:,i]) > 1):
                    #storing all the grades in a variabel - in random order
                    unsortedgrades = grades[:,i]
                    #sorting all the grades from lowest to highest
                    sortedgrades1 = np.sort(unsortedgrades)
                    #slicing the lowest grade out using indexing
                    sortedgrades = sortedgrades1[1::]
                    #finding the final grade as the mean of the n-1 grades
                    gradesFinal = np.mean(sortedgrades)
    return gradesFinal
```

Comment: Can you give examples of two columns, one of which is equal to -3 and the other is not?

Comment: Why don't you use `any` as suggested by the error message - and your own comment?

Answer (score 1):

`grades[:,i]` returns the ith column of the array. This means that it is an array with one element for each row.

You cannot use `if grades[:,i]==-3:` because `grades[:,i]==-3` returns a boolean array, which cannot be used  in an if statement.

If you want to check if any grade in that column == -3, you can use `-3 in grades[:,i]`.

Comment: numpy can compare an array with a integer.  but  the result is a boolean array, which cannot be used in an if statement